# How to cook Mixed grains all together in one pot

Tags: grains

I purchased a bag of organic mixed grains with 7 different types together and any directions, which there does not seem to be any, is in Chinese so I have no idea how to cook this.  this package includes brown and sweet rice, barley, millet, red, kidney and black eye peas.  Help?

Comment: For future reference Google has an app available on Apple and Android devices called Google Translate that can take a picture and translate many languages with fair results. I have used it for my occasional trips to my local Asian grocery stores and, if not perfect, can help in these situations.

Comment: Also feel free to post a picture of the back - a fair number of us on here can read Chinese.

Comment: Typically, mixes like that are cooked on the brown rice/ porridge setting of your rice cooker. The Kidney beans give me pause though. They may be an overnight on "warm" setting deal.

Answer (score 3):

Some of them aren't grains, and they'll be the limiting factor.

In particular red kidney beans must be boiled for a good few minutes to remove [phytohaemagglutinin](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phytohaemagglutinin). If you treat the whole lot as beans, you won't go far wrong, though the actual grains are likely to end up rather soft, a short of porridge with beans in. This is probably intentional.

So I'd soak overnight, then boil hard in fresh water for long enough to make the kidney beans safe (sources vary from 10 to 30 minutes). Then I'd drain and slow cook on high with whatever flavours you'd like for 6-8 hours, or simmer gently for a little less time. Alternatively you could pressure cook them.

Answer (score 1):

As the cooking time for most of the grains and beans falls into the same ballpark, around 50 minutes to 70 minutes depending on the exact heat, I think I would take this approach:

1. Rinse your mix in cool water (just as you would when cooking only rice) until the water runs clear. This will eliminate excess starch.
2. Place the grains and beans in a pot with your desired cooking liquid. This can be water with or without seasoning or some type of stock - whatever you like.
3. Bring to a boil and then reduce to a simmer and cover.
4. Check periodically and stir, making sure to add more cooking liquid if necessary. After about 45 minutes you can start checking for doneness.
5. When done to your liking, remove from the heat. If using as a soup type dish, you're good to go. If you want the grains and beans dry, you can drain any excess liquid.

Answer (score 1):

I do cook mixed grains (lentils, rice, quinoa) together many a times and the easiest way to start cooking them is on a stovetop (where we can keep an eye on the dish).
As these mixed grains have different cooking temperature+time, it's best to cook them on medium to low heat.

- It sounds like a vegetarian chili packaging, does it come with any seasoning too?
- Since it has 'Red kidney beans + black eyed peas', I would suggest soaking the 1 cup of this mix overnight in water or atleast 5-6hrs.
- I'd check the seasoning on packet and simmering the soaked mix (along with water) over medium heat.
- Once it's bubble, reduce the heat and cover cook.

(I have couple of dishes on my blog with mixed grains and you can try with this mix) https://www.easycookingwithmolly.com/2019/01/slow-cooker-curried-lentil-quinoa-chili/ 
Thanks, Molly